# Importing Notes with Privacy / Privacy level for Notes

Tags: import, privacy

We have a client that wants to import private notes.

(1) Is it possible to import note with privacy? There is not an option, when importing, to specify a particular row as "Author of"; any imported note will be attributed to the importer. Nor do I see an option to specify a particular row as "Privacy"; all notes I've imported thus far enter as privacy none.

(2) Under Option groups, there is a Privacy level for Notes. Within this section, you can add a privacy level beyond Author only or None. But I do not see what this group corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [API Import](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) extension which adds a lot more options than the Civi Import Wizard